# DocuSign quickstart example nothing happens

Tags: docusignapi

I have followed the instructions to implement Docusign quickstart... I have added quickstart to my server, and then with the composer I have installed the example scripts too.

However, after all settings correctly made (at least that is what I think), when I try to load it, nothing happens. Literally nothing: no error, but nothing loaded either.

http://dealstream.innovativesites.eu/dealstream-php/src/EG001EmbeddedSigning.php

Please have a look and try to give me some advise.

Thanks,
Attila.

Comment: 1. Try to load it from localhost, not external URL
2. Try to go to the top first, not the specific URL
3. What web server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The Quickstart is designed to load a home page that let you log in and lists all the code examples.
I know PHP developers typically would just try to run a specific PHP file, but that's not how we designed the quickstart.

You need to run http://localhost:8080/public assuming that you set 8080 as the port.

You can find instructions for XAMPP web server here -
https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php