# Docusign quickstart PHP example runs, but nothing happens

Tags: php, docusignapi

My issue is similar to the one at [DocuSign quickstart example nothing happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67544936/docusign-quickstart-example-nothing-happens).

Here is more information:

1. I have installed the example into my development website. I have adjusted ds_config.php so that 'app_url' points to the root of my website. It is unclear if that is what it should be set to, or whether it should be set to the example code index.php. In any case, it now points to my website index page.
2. I run the index.php that is part of the example under debugging and trace through the code.
3. Each line of code runs without errors.
4. At the end of the example index.php, my website loads. The address bar shows https://local.rephunter.net/?page=select_api. There is a comment about setting that query string variable, so that "app_url/index.php?page=ds_callback to your Integration Key." If that was set properly, would example docs show?

Based on the documentation, I was expecting "a login page that shows example documents" or something like that. But something is still missing to get that result.

How do I close the gap and get the example documents?

EDIT 1:

I realized that I was trying to run the index.php in ../Quick_ACG/public, and that I should instead run the one in ../public. Doing that does give an example document for the World Wide Corp.

There are no other samples shown.

There is no apparent way to sign the document. Are there instructions about what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had set it up on your localhost, when you run your application, you would navigate to `http://localhost:<port>/public` (public is the folder where index.php is located) where it would kickstart the project.

Based on your description, it sounds like that's what you're doing (may need to be app_url/public since in my application, public is where index.php rests). Try adding app_url/index.php?page=ds_callback to the list of redirect URIs on your integration key.

Comment: Your suggestion made me realize that I should use the ../public directory. I was using ../Quick_ACG/public because that is what I thought I should use based on the type of signing I requested during the creation of the Quickstart. See my edit to the main question.

Comment: Routing to ../public directly opens the world wide corp docx? Something's not right. If it was working as expected, it should navigate you to a DocuSign sign in url to log in for authorisation.

Comment: Agreed this is not what I was expecting. I dropped in the code in the directory structure into a development website instance. Then modified ds_config.php on the app_url lines only pointing to my site. It was unclear whether "url of the application" means the site url, or something else. However, I did talk to Docusign sales folks, and it appears we may be going with PowerForms instead of the eSignature API.